# useEffect stuck on loop when checking props

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I have a component that displays the meeting of a "call" and takes in the `call` object as a prop. In that object is a `created_by` which has the `id` of the user that created the call. So in my useEffect I want to get the rest of the users information from its id.

```
    const userDetails = useSelector(state => state.userDetails)
    const { loading, error, user } = userDetails

    useEffect(() => {
        if(props.call) {
            dispatch(getUserDetails(props.call.created_by))
        }
    }, [props, user, dispatch])
```

So as you can see, I check if `props.call` is truthy, if it is, dispatch the action to get the user details using the `created_by`. However this creates an infinite loop of the dispatch. I have tried doing `if(props.call && !user)` but that does nothing at all

All code before render method:

````
const call = props.call
    const userInfo = props.userInfo

    const dispatch = useDispatch()

    const userDetails = useSelector(state => state.userDetails, shallowEqual)
    const { loading, error, user } = userDetails

    useEffect(() => {
        if(props.call.created_by) {
            dispatch(getUserDetails(props.call.created_by))
        }
    }, [props.call.created_by])```
````

Comment: Isn't the problem that `props` are an object which is passed by reference, hence the `props` form every render are always considered different (even thought the contents are the same), because `{} !== {}`? Possible solution: pull the value which should cause rerender out from props. Also, do you need to have `dispatch` in dependency array? It would cause the same issue (function is subtype of object in JS).

Comment: Still looping unfortunately

Comment: Where is the the `user` coming from then and what's the type of `user`? If it's an object from the redux store received via `useSelector`, you can try to use the second argument, `shallowEqual` (which compares the objects by its contents, not the reference).

Comment: @HynekS I have it working now, however the component is getting rendered in a map function. Now an issue is arising where the user doesn't seem to be resetting after each call. So the created_by user is the same every time. When that is in fact not the case

Comment: There is likely an issue that you are updating something via `useDispatch`, which cause new props coming to the component, which is triggering `useEffect` again… hence the infinite loop. But I've encountered similar issues caused by the hot reloading in an old Gatsby version as well, so you can also e. g. try building the app and see if it also happens in production bundle…

Comment: It would be probably better if you show more of the surrounding context. It is hard to guess from the snippet. If some variable didn't update as expected, it is probably a so called 'stale prop' being caught in a closure.

Comment: @HynekS I have edit the question

Comment: You probably need to pull some primitive value which is being changed (e. g. some numeric ID) out from the `call` prop and put it in the dependency array of `useEffect`. If it is empty, it is triggered only on the first render. Also, try to change `useSelector(state => state.userDetails)` to `useSelector(state => state.userDetails, shallowEqual)`. You need to import `shallowEqual` from 'react-redux`.

Comment: @HynekS I have updated my code, the same seems to be still happening. They are all created by the same user

Comment: I suspect that the `if(props.call.created_by)` line should also contain check if the user details are not present or if the ids are not the same. You should call `dispatch` only if the user detail is not present yet, or if the `created_by` variable changed (another user). I would also double checked the `state => state.userDetails` getter; it seems to me more reasonable to store user e. g. in object and access it like `state => state.userDetails[userId]`. I assume that this is just a temporary object being overwritten every time `getUserDetail` receives new data, which might also be a culprit.

Comment: @HynekS I came up with a solution. I loaded a list of users in the system and in the useEffect I checked if `props.call.created_by` was set and if it was l used `.find()` to find a user with the matching id. 

Then set it to a state variable

Comment: Glad to read you've got your code working.